# Split string variable into an array

Tags: ruby

just wondering how I would split a string variable up letter by letter and make it an array

my `word` variable is a randomly selected word from an array of words:

```
word = $file_Arr[rand($file_Arr.length)]
```

how would I then split this word into individual letters and add them to an array?

**example:** if word pulls the word "hello" from `$file_Arr` how would I make an array like:
 `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]` out of my `word` variable

All I've been able to find online is people doing it with strings they type in and splitting on a comma, but how would I do it from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#chars`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars

```
2.3.1 :009 > "Hello World".chars
=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks, any idea how to remove the "\n" off the end? since it's adding an extra character to the array?

Comment: flanelman, if your string is `str`, you can write `str.chomp.chars` to first remove the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

First you can get a random word using `sample`. Then you can split the word into characters using `chars`.

```
irb(main):004:0> ["hi", "there"].sample.chars
=> ["h", "i"]
irb(main):005:0> ["hi", "there"].sample.chars
=> ["t", "h", "e", "r", "e"]
```

The result is different when called multiple times.

As far as you last question, you should be able to call `chars` the same way on a variable.

```
irb(main):006:0> x = "hi"
=> "hi"
irb(main):007:0> x.chars
=> ["h", "i"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is exactly what I was after! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!